# How to print a field from the content of a node using Omega 4 Layouts?

Tags: theming, 7

I'm designing a web with Drupal and my theme is a subtheme of Omega 4. I'm using Context/Context Omega and Omega Layouts.

I have a node type("Product node", for example) that has a title field(like default node), a subtitle field called field_subtitle, and the rest of the content.

Since I need to use CSS just for the subtitle field, I need to put it in a div separately from the rest of the content. So I would like to print the title, like it does by default, print the subtitle, and print the rest of the content.

What I have made in my product-layout.tpl.php, searching for this kind of things is:

```
  <div id = "title">
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
      <h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']['field_subtitle']); ?>
  </div>
  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Or maybe changing the

```
<?php print render($page['content']['field_subtitle']); ?>
```

for

```
<?php print render($content['field_subtitle']); ?>
```

, but didn't got it to work. It doesn't give any error mistakes, but it doesn't separate field_subtitle from content, since if I remove the last line of this snippet, all content dissapear, even the subtitle. So... how can I print the subtitle in a separated way that the rest of the content? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: use node.tpl for node specific markup

Comment: Thanks for the comment. At the end, I used the page.tpl, because I couldn't get variables declared in node.tpl, don't know why.